# How to match same values in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

For example if this is my array:

```
[
  {a: "b"},
  {a: "b"},
  {a: "c"},
  {a: "c"},
]
```

How can I modify the array so that if there is more `a` with the same value they get put in the same index:

```
[
  {
    a: "b",
    a1: "b"
  },
  {
    a: "c",
    a1: "c"
  },
]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```js
var arr = [
  {a: "b"},
  {a: "b"},
  {a: "c"},
  {a: "c"}
];

var arr2 = [];
var arr3 = [];

Object.keys(arr).forEach(key => {
    Object.keys(arr[key]).forEach(keyx => {
        if (!(arr[key][keyx] in arr2)) {
            arr2[arr[key][keyx]] = {};
        }
        var k = keyx;
        var x = 1;
        var i = true;
        while (i === true) {
            if (!(k in arr2[arr[key][keyx]])) {
                i = false;
                arr2[arr[key][keyx]][k] = arr[key][keyx];
            }
            k = keyx + x;
            x++;
        }
    })
});

for (i in arr2) {
    arr3.push(arr2[i]);
}



//arr3 is the expected array
console.log(arr3);
```